# Databinding in XBAP throws reflection error

Tags: xbap

I have a listbox that I'm binding to a collection of objects.

In the code behind, I get a list of the jobs and bind it to the listbox items source:

```
List<JobEntity> jobList = new List<JobEntity>();
Job j = new Job();
jobList = j.LoadJobs(pageSize, pageIndex);
lbxJobs.ItemsSource = jobList;
```

In the xaml, I then try and access some of the properties of the job.

```
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <WrapPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" Margin="5 0" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=HiringCompany}" Margin="5 0" />
            </WrapPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

This works fine for a normal wpf application, but as an xbap app it throws an error that basically says it can't get the value because Reflection Permissions were denied.

> System.Windows.Data Error: 16 : Cannot
>   get 'HiringCompany' value (type
>   'String') from '' (type 'JobEntity').
>   BindingExpression:Path=HiringCompany;
>   DataItem='JobEntity'
>   (HashCode=64844482); target element is
>   'TextBlock' (Name=''); target property
>   is 'Text' (type 'String')
>   TargetInvocationException:'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
>   Property accessor 'HiringCompany' on
>   object 'JobSearch.Classes.JobEntity'
>   threw the following
>   exception:'JobSearch.Classes.JobEntity.get_HiringCompany()'
>   ---> System.MethodAccessException: JobSearch.Classes.JobEntity.get_HiringCompany()
>   ---> System.Security.SecurityException:
>   Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission,
>   mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed

Has any one run into this before or found a workaround for this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the answer to my own question. I didn't have my JobEntity class explicitly declared as "public". Doing that resolved the issue.